# Filtering MySQL results-How can PHP remember selected category?

Tags: php

I have one question.
There is my PHP project and the 'browse' page,which contains results from my mysql table. 
I added a filtering script which works good,but everytime i switch from one page to another it breaks and shows all results (the 'else' starts).
Is there any way for PHP to remember chosen category?

```
$c = new Pagination;

    if (isset($_POST['filter_category_button'])) {
        $category = $_POST['filter_category'];
        $c->setDefaults();
        $c->countAds("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category';");
        $c->PagenoOffset();
        $c->SelectLimitAd("SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category'");
    } else {
        $c->setDefaults();
        $c->countAds("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads;");
        $c->PagenoOffset();
        $c->SelectLimitAd("SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads");
    }
```

Below there is a pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session, or store last filter used in some file. I suggest you to use session, also a bit clean up will help you debug and prevent code duplication eg.:

```
// make sure this is called in top level where nothing is rendered before
session_start();
$filter = $_SESSION['filter_category'] ?? null;
$c = new Pagination;

$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads";
$sql = "SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads";
$where = " ";
if (isset($_POST['filter_category_button']) || $filter) {
   $category = $_POST['filter_category'] ?? $filter;
   $_SESSION['filter_category'] = $category;

   $where.= " WHERE category LIKE '".$category"'";
}

$sqlCount .= $where;
$sql .= $where;    


$c->setDefaults();
$c->countAds($sqlCount);
$c->PagenoOffset();
$c->SelectLimitAd($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always store data in $_SESSION variable, for example.

```
$c = new Pagination;

if (isset($_POST['filter_category_button'])) {
   $_SESSION['filter_category'] = $_POST['filter_category']
   $category = $_POST['filter_category'];
   $c->setDefaults();
   $c->countAds("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category';");
   $c->PagenoOffset();
   $c->SelectLimitAd("SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category'");
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['filter_category'])) {
   $category = $_SESSION['filter_category'];
   $c->setDefaults();
   $c->countAds("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category';");
   $c->PagenoOffset();
   $c->SelectLimitAd("SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads WHERE category LIKE '$category'");
} else {
   $c->setDefaults();
   $c->countAds("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM ads;");
   $c->PagenoOffset();
   $c->SelectLimitAd("SELECT id_ad,title,price,image_name,category,content FROM ads");
}
```